# Conditional coloring plotly shiny

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart, plotly, reactive

I have a simple data frame in Shiny & would like to make a bar plot with plot_ly that would have conditional coloring based on the values (if profit > 0 green, else red). How to refer to a certain column in the color property?

```
 data<-reactive({names<-c("Initial", "New")
  revenue<-c(revenue1(),revenue2())
  costs<-c(input$costs, input$costs)
  profit1<-c(profit(), profit2())
  data<-data.frame(names, revenue, costs, profit1)
  data 
  })

  output$profit_bar<-renderPlotly(
    p<-data() %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~names, y = ~revenue, type = 'bar', name = 'Revenue', marker = list(color="#e5f4ea")) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~profit1, name = 'Profit',marker = list(color=ifelse(profit1>0,"#009933","FF6666"))) 

  )
```

I get an error:  *object 'profit1' not found.*
I also tried other options (e.g. data[,4] but no success. Outside shiny, the code is working correct.

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Please provide a MWE. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), how to create it, that would help us try & get a solution from your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the issue by myself.

1. I changed the name of the dataframe *data -> data_bar* (to omit collisions with the function in base R).
2. Made a reactive color palette outside renderPlotly (profit is the 4th column).:

   `col<-reactive({ifelse(data_bar()[,4]>0,"#009933","FF6666")})`
3. Referred to this palette inside renderPlotly.

   ```
   output$profit_bar<-renderPlotly(p<-data_bar() %>%
     plot_ly(x = ~names, y = ~revenue, type = 'bar', name = 'Revenue', marker = list(color="#e5f4ea")) %>%
     add_trace(y = ~profit1, name = 'Profit',marker = list(color=col()))
   ```

   )